# I'm getting "invalid conversion from `void*` to `std::complex<double>*"

Tags: c++, calloc

I have the following code below,

```
std::complex<double>** x;
x = calloc(10,sizeof(complex <double> *));
```

This code failed to compile with the following error message.

```
error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'std::complex<double>*' [-fpermissive]
```

How can I successfully compile? Why does this code fail to compile?

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: Just grab a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465). Mixing C and C++ is never a good idea. But to answer you, just use `new[]` or `std::vector`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, I didn't downvote, but the question really show lack of any research whatsoever. That's a reason for downvote, don't you think? The OP doesn't tell at all what he has done to figure out what the error means and why he's given this error. Besides, [sympathy upvote is not how the system is meant to be used](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87487/169090).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, `void *` doesn't automatically cast to other pointers (unlike in C). So if you use `malloc` and the family in C++, you need to cast the result yourself.

However, you should note that `malloc` doesn't understand C++'s constructors. So if you want to allocate a C++ object (not a C struct for example, or more precisely a POD), you should use `new` (and `delete`/`delete[]` correspondingly) which correctly takes care of constructors and destructors.

Alternatively, you can use one of the many structures provided by the standard library, such as `std::vector`.

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to write C++ as if it were C, which allows dangerous implicit conversions like this.

To allocate a dynamic array of size 10, use

```
std::vector<std::complex<double>> numbers(10);
```

and, if you really want a pointer to the first element

```
x = numbers.data();
```

Comment: Or `std::addressof(numbers[0])`.

Comment: That is not really the same structure, in the original the `x` variable is a pointer to pointers that would map better to `std::vector<std::complex<double>*>`. Not saying that the code might not benefit with this simplification though...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: The declaration of `x` was missing when I wrote the answer; I inferred its type from the error message. If the OP actually wants a 2-dimensional array, then generalising this to a vector of vectors isn't a bad option (although there may be better options).

Answer (score 2):

## The problems.

This code from the question, …

```
    x = calloc(10,sizeof(complex <double> *));
```

is ungood for two reasons:

- unlike C, C++ does not have an implicit conversion *from* `void*`, and
- creating a jagged array by means of C++ `new` is bad enough, doing it with the C level allocation functions is general an abomination (except where required by some function that one needs to call).

The first bullet point is why it fails to compile in C++.

---

## What to do.

A purely *technical* fix is to use a cast, and then preferably a C++ named cast such as `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast`. Both work fine in practice for conversion from `void*`. However, in my opinion `reinterpret_cast` expresses the conceptual operation more correctly, so I’d choose that  – *if* I chose to cast.

A slightly better solution is to use C++ `new` instead of C `calloc`. With `new` you have to add an empty parenthesis at the end to to get the guaranteed zero-initialization of `calloc`. But the main problem is still that it's every low level and difficult (much work) to get right.

A much better general solution is to use a C++ container class.

The standard library offers `std::vector`, with which the jagged array can be constructed like this:

```
typedef complex<double> Complex;
typedef vector<Complex> ComplexVec;
typedef vector<ComplexVec> ComplexVec2D;

ComplexVec2D x( 10 );
```

Then each `ComplexVec` can just be resized, since `std::vector` is a dynamically sized array.

---

## What to do if you really want a MATRIX.

If you really want a *matrix*, i.e. an array of arrays of equal length, then instead of a jagged array consider a C++ class which just provides 2D indexing into a single vector.

In C++03-style it can go like this (off the cuff code):

```
typedef complex<double> Complex;

class ComplexMatric
{
private:
    vector<Complex> items_;
    int             width_;

public:
    Complex& operator()( int x, int y )
    { return items_[y*width_ + x]; }

    Complex const& operator()( int x, int y ) const
    { return items_[y*width_ + x]; }

    ComplexMatrix( int w, int h )
        : items_( w*h )
        , width_( w )
    {}
};
```

And you'd use it like this:

```
ComplexMatrix x( 10, some_height );
```

This includes doing proper allocation and deallocation, and even supporting copying by assignment.

Disclaimer: code untouched by compiler's hands.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `calloc`, try using `new[]` operator instead. This is the C++ way to dynamically create an array.

```
x = new complex<double>[10];
```

The `new[]` returns a pointer to whatever type followed the operator, in this case it is a pointer with type `complex<double>` which points to an array of `complex<double>` with 10 elements inside.

Be aware, though, you have to use `delete[]` operator to deallocate the memory (not `free()`). Otherwise no one know what's going to happen :-).

```
delete[] x;
```

Comment: Even better: instead of using `new[]` and `delete[]`, just use `std::vector` :)

Comment: Well I'd say an array is not a vector. If the OP really need an array, creating an array might be a better choice. It really depends.

But I agree that, in general, using vector is better.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `x` is of type `std::complex<double>*`, you get this error because `calloc` returns a `void` pointer. Without `-fpermissive` implicit casts are not allowed. So, you'll have to cast between `void*` and `std::complex<double>*`. However, in C++ it is recommended to use `new` instead of `malloc` or `calloc`, and personally I'd recommend you to use `std::vector`.

Comment: x is defined std::complex <double> **x . I want that x is Two-dimensional array

Comment: Then this is a bit more complex, have a look at [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new).

Comment: Please *don't* look at that question, since it's using a bunch of `new`.

Comment: @DeadMG well, he asked for it and I answered, I never said it's the best solution for his problem.